Google Cloud App - Publishing only for a perm token
I created an app to connect to my website. My website is only available to people that have a QR code. I have a gallery in which users can upload photos to my website.
If I publish my app in order to allow my token to last longer than 7 days, does this allow anyone to access the google drive linked to the app?
Also, is there a way to view how many days are left on the token?
I have not yet published my app but I want to essentially publish a public app without having anything of use to the public on it.
